# Reduce duplication of binary files across C# projects in solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working in a repository with a lot of test projects that include many binary files. A lot of these files are duplicated from project to project, resulting in i) massive duplication in the source code, and ii) massive file-copying and duplication in the build folders. Exemplified it could look like this:

```
Solution
 ┣ Project A
 ┃ ┣ bin
 ┃ ┃ ┗ release
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ BinaryFile1
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ BinaryFile2
 ┃ ┣ BinaryFile1
 ┃ ┗ BinaryFile2
 ┗ Project B
 ┃ ┣ bin
 ┃ ┃ ┗ release
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ BinaryFile1
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ BinaryFile2
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ BinaryFile3
 ┃ ┣ BinaryFile1
 ┃ ┣ BinaryFile2
 ┃ ┗ BinaryFile3
```

The files in the projects are set up with `<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>`.

#### What I am looking for

A way to reduce the amount of duplication in the source code and, if possible, in the build output folders.

#### What I have tried

I have tried create a separate "data" project containing the binary files and then referencing that project from other projects. That removes the duplication in the source code. However, it results in *all* the files being copied to the build output for *all* projects referencing the data-project. This is not desirable.

I have also tried to *not* reference the data-project from any of the test-projects, and then from the test-projects reference the needed files by adding them with "Add -> Existing item -> Add as link". This also removes the duplication in the source code and in the build output, but it results in the files only being copied to the output of the data-project, and the tests in the test-projects failing because they cannot access the files they need.

Comment: You can build all projects to the same, common bin folder. There are some problems with that approach with respect to dependencies, but if you don't use different versions of dependent packages within your solution, it usually works fine.

Comment: So what you don't like are tests that need these files to be present in the same directory as the test.  Then don't do that.

Comment: @PMF Nice to know. Unfortunately, this is not something that I can do with this solution.

Comment: @HansPassant I am sorry, but I do not understand your comment. The tests need to be there, and they need access to the files. The files also need to be under version control. This is not something that can be changed. What I am seeking is a way to not duplicate the files across the test projects.